# How would I flatten a bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

so I'm an a bit of a blender noob and I'm having trouble figuring out how to straighten/flatten this curve (on the Z axis).

Can someone explain how to do this?
[image]

Comment: select all of the control points and use the scale command to set the scale to 0 on Z.  If you type SZ0<return> you will accomplish this.  It raises some points and lowers others until all of the points have the same Z coordinate.

Comment: ^ Thanks Marty!